# Ubuntu 17.10 Major security issue at login

Tags: login, 17.10, password, security

I have a fresh install, 5 days old, no major changes I can think of.
I lock the machine when I walk away.
Randomly, I can log back in by just moving the mouse, I shouldn't be able to do that.  Seems about 70% of the time it asks for a password, and 30% it just logs in to my running session.
At first I thought maybe it was me, so I've been VERY careful to hit lock.
This morning I sat down at my desk, bumped the mouse and there was my full session as I left it the night before without requiring a password.
I don't even know where to start looking for this bug.
What info is required to find this?

The only observation, so far, is that it seems to take time, I can't reproduce it by locking and immediately logging back in, it always asks for pw that way.  It has only unlocked by mouse, after long breaks, like lunch time, or overnight.

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
```

Comment: could it be your screenlocker crashed?

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior.

Comment: @mbeyss - How would I check that.  What is the name of the screenlocker?  It appears to that big pinkish screen with the list of updates, but instead of asking for PW it just logs in.  There are no errors in syslog, kernlog, or auth.log.

Comment: And it just happened again this morning.  Locked at about 6:00 last night and at 8:25 this morning free access.

Comment: @dale: I actually do not know how Ubuntu 17.10 handles screen locking. I think this might be worth a bug report

Comment: I've submitted a bug (hopefully this is the correct link) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1754156

Comment: @heynnema - you should go "me too" the bug.

Comment: The link is bad.

Comment: I think because it is a security issue they made the page private.  The link works for me.  Not sure what to do. It would be better if multiple poeple could add comments.

Comment: I changed it to public, link should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason my screen is unlocking.  I'm using takeabreak which calls "gnome-screensaver-command -d" at it's next scheduled wakeup time.  So that closes this issue.  I'm going to open anther topic about why "gnome-screensaver-command -d" unlocks my screen without a password. New question [gnome-screensaver-command -d unlocks without password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018580/)