# gnome-screensaver-command -d unlocks without password

Tags: gnome, password, lock-screen, screensaver

Ubuntu 17.10

Related to, but separate from [Ubuntu 17.10 Major security issue at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012420/).

When I physically lock my screen by clicking the lock button I expect to have to type a password to get back in.  I'm using "takeabreak", which is always running in the background "takeabreak" calls "gnome-screensaver-command -d" on it's scheduled wakeup to unlock the screen.  That is fine, but I would expect it to be presenting the password screen, not just opening up my desktop.

Are my expectations wrong?  Is there a way to force it to ask for a password?  I'm new to gnome, so point me in the correct direction if you can.

Comment: Try -l switch. It works for me

Comment: I'm clicking the lock icon in the panel, not running it by hand.  Can I control that somehow?  In settings I have "Screen Lock" set to "on" - must have been by default, I didn't change it.  Either way isn't it the problem of "-d" unlocking without a password.  That, to me, seems the real issue.